# reloadData in MasterView from DetailView

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, reloaddata

I ran into an issue similar to this earlier on the iPhone, but the same solution doesn't seem to apply to the iPad environment. My goal is to call my method `forceReload`, defined in my RootViewController, that will reload the countdown_table's data in the RootView from the DetailView once a modal is dismissed. `forceReload` works fine when called directly from the RootViewController, but I can't seem to point to point to the RootViewController from the DetailView.

I've tried using

```
RootViewController *root_view = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[root_view forceReload];
[root_view.countdown_table reloadData];
```

But that only points to the Navigation Controller, not the View Controller inside of it. Even when the modal is dismissed, RootViewController's *viewWillAppear* does not fire.

How can I point to this file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using notifications, i.e., register RootViewController as an observer for notifications that your DetailView or any view may send.

in RootViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(forceReload) 
                                             name:@"reloadRequest" 
                                           object:nil];
```

viewDidUnload or in dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

And in your DetailViewController or your modal view (you didn't say they're the same), put this right before you dismiss the view or exactly when you need RootViewController to call forceReload:

```
NSNotification *notif = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"reloadRequest" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notif];
```

Comment: I've tried this in the reverse order (reloadData in Detail from Master) but no luck. Any advice on that?

Comment: @LukeIrvin, can you post code for this? Also, won't a reloadData in Detail's view(Will|Did)Appear do?