# reload MasterView in UISplitView iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uisplitview

I am working on UISplitView , I have a button in detailViewController I wants on a button click. show the MasterViewController and  reload the table data of MasterViewController.

how it is possible, please provide me help

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please browse through the following links I hope they offer some solution ....

[Refreshing Master TableView of a UISplitView Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065849/refreshing-master-tableview-of-a-uisplitview-controller)

[reloadData in MasterView from DetailView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479780/reloaddata-in-masterview-from-detailview)

Comment: thanks links are helpful for me. and my problem solved :), I wants to know that how I disappear or show the MainView control programmatically. I wants on button click of DetailView, MainView show to the user.

Comment: Then add the appropriate action or selector to the button to make it navigate from one view to the other ....

Comment: I am working on Split view , can you provide me example to navigator from one view to other on button click of DetailView